# See if canvas has any data (other than black)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a small app where I take a picture and extract RGB channels (put them in 3 separate canvases) and convert them to alpha mask see below.[image]

I have to check whether the generated channel has any data in it (other than black). What would be the most efficient way of checking that?

The most accurate would be to loop through all pixels and see whether some of the values are bigger than 0. But I would like to avoid that to save some processor speed (especially as the web app will be used on mobiles/tablets).

I have tried using a temp canvas where I save a layer and scale it down to 1px and then check the image data. This works but is not accurate. I also tried to scale down to 10x10px, it's more accurate but still on the 3rd picture it gives me false.

I use this simple code to scale the results down

```
ctx.drawImage(bc,0,0,8,10)
fdata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,8,10)
```

For the images shown above. This method gives me:

1st pic: 0,0,0,253 (detected data)

2nd pic: 0,0,0,2 (detected)

3rd pic: 0,0,0,255 (not detected).

any ideas?

Comment: What do you use to scale it? Can you visually inspect the 10x10px result? If the interpolation from the scaling eliminates your white pixels, well...

Comment: as said in my post, I scale it down by using this line `ctx.drawImage(bc,0,0,8,10)` (8x10px in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using Canvas.toDataURL to compare the base64 representation of the image to a self-generated all black image of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do also : 
Use a temporary, one time instantiated canvas that has, say 16X16 size, then for each test :
- clear this canvas.
- loop through each 16X16 block of the original image and copy it on the canvas.
- check the imageData of the canvas.

something like (untested) :

```
var isBlank = (function () {
    var blockSize = 16;
    var tstCv = document.createElement('canvas');
    tstCv.width = blockSize;
    tstCv.height = blockSize;
    var tstCtx = tstCv.getContext('2d');

    function _isBlank(tgtCanvas) {
        tstCtx.clearRect(0, 0, blockSize, blockSize);
        for (var y = 0; y < tgtCanvas.height; y += blockSize) {
            for (var x = 0; x < tgtCanvas.width; x += blockSize) {
                tstCtx.drawImage(tgtCanvas, x, y, blockSize, blockSize, 0, 0, blockSize, blockSize);
            }
        }
        var data = tstCtx.getImageData(0, 0, blockSize, blockSize).data;
        var i = 0,
            l = data.length;
        while (i != l) {
            if ( data[i+3]!=255 /* some test on data[i+?] */ ) return false;
            i += 4;
        }
        return true;
    }  
    return _isBlank;    
})();
```

It should be very efficient, since you'll use the graphic card to sum-up pixels block by block, and you only check a small amount of data by hand after that.

Comment: @sahbeewah's comparing .toDataURL to an all-black .toDataURL is surprisingly fast. I suspect it's even faster if you just compare the .toDataURL().length. If you use .toDataURL().length you could all-black the original canvas before you start using it for drawing and save its .toDataURL().length. Anyway, it would be interesting to see a perf test between .toDataURL().length and the method you propose

Comment: @markE I wonder how accurate the toDataURL method is though considering this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/23501676/322395 (the lossless nature of canvas). Really interesting idea regardless though.

Comment: @Loktar. Ah, yes...good point(!)--the put !== get problem.  It leads me to need more info about the techniques the questioner used to isolate RGB channels and to create alpha masks. Also, I'm just guessing at what his code might be, but seems to me that non-black pixels could be identified earlier in the process--maybe as the channels are being created.