# HTML canvas returns "off-by-some" bytes from getImageData

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I found that `getImageData` of an HTML canvas seems to return incorrect byte values.

I generated a 1x1 px image with the following Python code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[12, 187, 146, 62]]], dtype=np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(a).save('image.png')
```

I converted the image to base64 to include it in this code snippet:

```js
let image = document.createElement('img');
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  let data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
  document.body.innerHTML = data;
});

image.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR4nGPg2T3JDgADyAGYmiSbAQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
```

When run in Firefox, it shows `12,189,148,62`. In Chromium it shows `12,185,144,62`. But the original values are `12,187,146,62`.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: For the record: It's possible to read the accurate byte values of an image using [WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60564905/1796523).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Firefox pre-multiplication rounding error

I can confirm that FF (Firefox) does indeed return the pixel value as `[12,189,148,62]`

When rendering to the canvas pixels are processed according to the value of [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) which defaults to [`"source-over"`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_srcover). The calculation is performed on pre multiplied alpha values for which FF seams to be rounding incorrectly.

**Note** that turning off alpha `canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: false})` for [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) the resulting pixels are FF `[3,46,36,255]` and Chrome `[3,45,35,255]`.

Chrome has the correct values as shown in the following snippet.

```js
// correct pre mult alpha 
console.log([12,187,146].map(c => Math.round(c * 62 / 255)) + "");
```

FF is rounding up for some reason and I would consider this a **bug**

This rounding error (in FF) is then effecting the result of [`"source-over"`](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_srcover) compositing when `alpha: true` resulting in the higher than expected values.

For more information on compositing [W3C Compositing and Blending](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/)

### Fix?

I can not suggest a fix, only to say that Chrome is rendering the image correctly, while FF is not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with premultiplied alpha! If I set the alpha byte to 255, the RGB bytes are reconstructed correctly. Apparently `putImageData` is [considered a lossy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23501676/1796523) if alpha is involved.

Comment: For reference: I have created a bug report for Firefox (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1613369).