# putImageData doesn't change the imageData of the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

From the code below you can see that I misunderstand how `putImageData` works:

```js
// create canvas:
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 2;
canvas.height = 1;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// grab its imageData:
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log(imageData.data);

// edit its imageData:
imageData.data[0] = 10;
console.log(imageData.data);

// put the edited image data onto the canvas:
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

// check that the edited data is actually on the canvas:
let finalImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log(finalImageData.data);
```

That code outputs these logs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I expected that last `console.log` to output `[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Where am I going wrong in my understanding here?

(To be sure, I've tested with Firefox and Chrome - same result. Definitely seems like a very fundamental misunderstanding on my part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the alpha to 255 or the canvas is just drawing something transparent, the data is a sequence of RGBA items

Your data output of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` can be represented as

| R | G | B | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Some good reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData

Here is your code but setting the alpha on the first pixel to 255

```js
// create canvas:
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 2;
canvas.height = 1;
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// grab its imageData:
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log(imageData.data);

// edit its imageData:
imageData.data[0] = 10;
imageData.data[3] = 255;
console.log(imageData.data);

// put the edited image data onto the canvas:
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

// check that the edited data is actually on the canvas:
let finalImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
console.log(finalImageData.data);
```

Comment: To be correct, the issue here is that the pixels are stored with their alpha premultiplied in the canvas buffer. So whatever-RGB x alpha-0 will be stored as 0. This formats allows for faster processing later. OP could have set the alpha to something else than 0 or 255 to get something in their R channel (though not necessarily the value they did set)

Comment: @Kaiido do you have some references to the `alpha premultiplied` I was running some test and getting some "interesting" results there is some calculation been done but does not look like a multiplication

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#premultiplied-alpha-and-the-2d-rendering-context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497925/how-can-i-stop-the-alpha-premultiplication-with-canvas-imagedata https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/5371